# Create selector with toggle buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I working in C# WPF with mvvm and I don't know how to design my application to create a selector.

I have a Class containing points:

```
public class MyCustomRectangle
{
    public MyCustomPoint Point1;
    public MyCustomPoint Point2;
    public MyCustomPoint Point3;
    public MyCustomPoint Point4;
}
```

My application contains an image. User can draw 4 points by clicking on the image. He have to select point to draw and click.

[image]

I wanted to do the selector as togglebuttons, binded on my MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyCustomRectangle _myPoints;
    public MyCustomRectangle MyPoints
    {
        get
        {
            return _myPoints;
        }
    }

    public int _selectedPointIndex;
    public int SelectedPointIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPointIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedPointIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int SelectedPoint
    {
        get
        {
            return MyPoints.GetPoint(SelectedPointIndex);
        }
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to easily bind my button to the view model. The behavior must be:

- All buttons are unchecked.
- If user check button 1, the button 1 will pass to checked and the SelectedPointIndex = 1
- If user check button 2, the button 2 will pass to checked and the SelectedPointIndex = 2 and button 1 is unchecked

Actually I have just:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Point 1"/>
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Point 2"/>
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Point 3"/>
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Point 4"/>
```

How can I simply bind my buttons?

Comment: why you don't use radio buttons and style them?

Comment: I'm not very expert in WPF, I don't know how to perform that. ToggleButton seemed to me easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RadioButtons` for your expected behaviour and style them like `ToggleButtons`. Using `RadioButtons` can be found here: https://www.wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html

Define style:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonLooksAsToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="RadioButton"/>
```

Use the style:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonLooksAsToggleButton}" />
```

Comment: It seems to be a good Idea. How can I get the checked radiobutton ?

Comment: in the given link it is the bound property `CurrentOption`